# Smart caret positioning in Vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to enable support for camel case in the Vscode?
I want the next word key binding (commonly <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd>) to select the next fragment of a word.

A feature similar to that found in the Eclipse IDE.
For example, in a method named: "**searchByName()**".
I could jump from "**search**" to "**By**" to "**Name**".

Answer (score 1):

The following commands should work:

**Right**

- cursorWordPartRight: <kbd>ctrl+alt+right</kbd>
- cursorWordPartRightSelect: <kbd>ctrl+shift+alt+right</kbd>
- deleteWordPartRight: <kbd>ctrl+alt+delete</kbd>

**Left**

- cursorWordPartLeft: <kbd>ctrl+alt+left</kbd>
- cursorWordPartLeftSelect: <kbd>ctrl+shift+alt+left</kbd>
- deleteWordPartLeft: <kbd>ctrl+alt+backspace</kbd>

Comment: thanks, only to clarify who has the same problem: I found these settings in: File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts. In my Vscode I needed to configure.